# How to get the source code of the built-in Calendar app in ecilipse emulator?

Tags: android, android-widget

could someone tell me the source code or file location of the Calendar APP in the emulator.

I catch two graph in the following link.

Thanks a lot!

[image: image one]
<sub>(source: [ppt.cc](http://ppt.cc/TW8u@.jpg))</sub>

[image: image one]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can find the calendar app source in googles android source repository.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/

Comment: Now i have another question. This project is without R.java
And i can't install it.

Comment: if you import the project in eclipse the [android developer tools plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) generates the R.java

Comment: I import it,but R.java still does not exist. 

and it have some error,like this one:

import com.android.calendar.extensions.AllInOneMenuExtensions;

Answer (score 0):

furthermore explaining on the accepted answer about compiling stock calendar app from aosp, short answer is: you can't

the app is compiled against the rom as a whole, which means it links to some other projects, therefore you cant just download the source code for one specific app and compile it. as per [eclipse project file](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/project.properties) and [android make file](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/Android.mk)

however, i do managed to get a compiled version out of the source code since they are only the open source part, some files, e.g.AllInOneMenuExtensions you mentioned, is not included. it will generate some error message when running, and you can notice both the visual and functionality are quite different (lacking) compared to the released version.
[my fork of calendar](https://github.com/1and1get2/google-calendar/tree/standalone)